# Positioning UITabBar at the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbar

I'm a beginner in iOS development. My question is: is it possible to position UITabBar at the top and how?
I can't position my UITabBar at the top of the view.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: @Fogmeister Why not?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Is it possible? Sure, but it violates the human interface guidelines.

### Screenshots:

[image: Portrait] [image: Landscape] [image: Storyboard]

### Code:

TabController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end
```

TabController.m:

```
#import "TabController.h"

@interface TabController ()

@end

@implementation TabController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [self.tabBar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];

    CGFloat tabSize = 44.0;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
    {
        tabSize = 32.0;
    }

    CGRect tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame;

    tabFrame.size.height = tabSize;

    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y;

    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame;

    // Set the translucent property to NO then back to YES to
    // force the UITabBar to reblur, otherwise part of the
    // new frame will be completely transparent if we rotate
    // from a landscape orientation to a portrait orientation.

    self.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    self.tabBar.translucent = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks aviatorKen89, i try to create (android fragments) in objective-c that is why i display tab bar in the top

Comment: is what I can do so via other methods ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: can i add just buttons in the top ?

Comment: Your question was about UITabBars, so you will need to ask another question instead. And yes, buttons at the top would work fine.

Comment: @AlgroDev I guess you're an Android Dev coming to iOS. Something to keep in mind ios != Android. They are two completely different operating systems. You may have something that works on android but that doesn't mean it will work for iOS. It may in fact completely clash with iOS. In iOS the user expects the tab bar to be along the bottom and navigation bar to be along the top. Careful that you do not put off users by presenting them with something so unexpected.

Comment: I don't understand how to achieve that, could someone write simple tutorial ?

Comment: Can someone point me to where in HIG it says that tab bars must be at bottom?

Comment: You should use toolbar for top bars.

Comment: "Is it possible? Sure, but it violates the human interface guidelines." Google do it in https://apps.apple.com/in/app/nybo/id1170384819#?platform=iphone

Answer (score 9):

**Swift3:** I achieve this by creating a custom class for `UITabBarController`:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

   @IBOutlet weak var financialTabBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // I've added this line to viewDidLoad
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        financialTabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:  financialTabBar.frame.size.height, width: financialTabBar.frame.size.width, height: financialTabBar.frame.size.height)
    }
```

Don't forget to set your Custom Class to `TabBarController`
[image]

The result would be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is a working swift 3 example of aviatorken89's code.

1. First create a new file.
2. Select source cocoa touch class.
3. Designate subclass of: UITabBarController
4. Name the class "CustomTabBarController" or whatever you'd like.
5. Add the following code to the class.

   ```
   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
       var tabFrame:CGRect = self.tabBar.frame
       tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y
       self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
   }
   ```
6. If you are using storyboard make sure to change the tab bar class to your custom class via the "Identity inspector".

Comment: Working like a charm

Comment: The problem this creates is that the view controllers are unaware of the tab bar controller being moved to the top. So the view doesn't have correct positioning.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 5

Add this code to your UITabBarViewController;

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let height = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY
    tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height ?? 0, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  }
```

It works for iOS > 13 and iOS < 13

Comment: Do you mean it works for everything *except* iOS 13?

Answer (score 4):

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
}
```

[image: storyboard][image]

**UPDATE IOS 11 ISSUE**

the code above doesnt work on ios 11. so here is workaround that i found.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to implement this for iPhoneX? @mnemonic23

Comment: i think it same with other iphone.
- create UITabBarController on storyboard
- subclass it. let say "TabViewController"
- set tabBar.frame like above code, inside the subclass.

Comment: How did you make the underline tint green line of the tab button when selected? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

subviews of TabbarController hide back of Tabbar .
so for fix use this code :

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController ,UITabBarControllerDelegate{

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        delegate = self
        selectedViewController?.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: tabBar.frame.size.height)
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
          selectedViewController?.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: tabBar.frame.size.height)
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked well the first time the screen is shown, however when you go to another screen, pop it off back to this screen, it undoes everything you initially set. How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom tab bar by making it yourself, but apple highly discourages mimicking a system control for a function it was not originally intended to do.

Once again, I discourage you to do so, because it violates the consistency of your app and system apps. But since I'm at it, here we go:

For a custom tab bar, you need to create a view that holds multiple buttons. You also need a container view *below* the `UITabBar` (because you want the `UITabBar` to be at the top). When a button is pressed, you change the `UIViewController` inside the container. 
Its quite simple, but of course, its strongly not recommended.

Comment: thanks, then how i can use (android fragments) in ios ?

Answer (score 1):

After Update to xCode 11.5. Added this code in my controller. work ios 13

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        renderTabPosition()
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }
private func renderTabPosition() {
        tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height + 5)        
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want something like an UITabBar on top then how about you create a custom UIView and add any number of UIButtons in it. Then link some ViewControllers with each button through Segue. Done!

You don't need to customise the UITabBar. As aviatorken89 said earlier, it is against the human interface guideline.

Comment: please provide the supporting link to this "against the human interface guideline".