# IOS: How to change the position of UITabbar to the top of view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbar

i am using `UITAbBar` in my project i want to change its position from bottom to top of view.
what code i have to put for this.

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   self.title = @"Welcome";


    _friendviewcontroller = [FriendsViewController new];
    _homeviewcontroller = [HomePageViewController new];
    _notifviewcontroller = [NotificationViewController new];
    _messageviewcontroller = [MessagesViewController new];

    self.tabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_homeviewcontroller,_messageviewcontroller,_friendviewcontroller,_notifviewcontroller, nil];

    //UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *item0 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *item3 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
}
```

Comment: Create subclass of UITabbarController and give the position what ever you want even you can customize each and every button with different size and style.

Comment: You can to do that ,I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29580094/3920648)

Answer (score 1):

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

// define a custom frame size for the entire tab bar controller that will be in the
// top of the screen.
CGRect tabBarFrame;
tabBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
tabBarController.view.frame = tabBarFrame;
```

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible with UITabBarController. It always stays at bottom.