# iOS tab bar controller adding a navigation button at the top of the controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

So I have a `UITabBarController` and it has three buttons on the bottom in my iOS app. I want to add another set of buttons at the top but not quite sure on how to do this. I tried adding a `UINavigationBar` and a navigation button, and adding a view in to it, adding just the buttons, ect.... but to no avail. It won't let me add anything to the `UITabBarController`. Is there a way to do this?
Thank you very much.

[image: StoryBoard]

Comment: can you display that how you are adding buttons in navigationBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way to that is to creat 3 buttons side by side and set their frame the way they divide the top of screen to 3 equals. it means u can create a tab bar with buttons manually.
but there's another way. i think this answer would help u
[Positioning UITabBar at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579992/positioning-uitabbar-at-the-top)

Answer (score 1):

To use the navigation bar you need a navigation controller. Now depending on your needs your tab bar controller should be inside a navigation controller or the other way around. If you want to be able to navigate away from the tab bar controller (have a screen without the tab bar) you should embed your tab bar controller into a navigation controller. If you only need the navigation bar for some tabs of the tab bar controller or you still want the tab bar to be visible all the time you should embed all (or just the ones than need a navigation bar) your root view controllers for each tab in navigation controllers. Finally if you do not need the navigation behaviour you could just put a regular view in the view controller that needs the bar at the top and some buttons in it and make them look the way you want.

You can embed a view controller in a navigation controller in a storyboard by selecting the view controller and the going to Edit->Embed in->Navigation controller.

Comment: You will give Edit, but its Editor please comform that

Answer (score 1):

Select the Any Tabbar ViewController then above the Menu -> Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller its select, if you get the Navigation Controller then if you add the Navigation Button at Top of the ViewController, example :

[image]