# Xamarin - Master page with tabs in center of page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to write a simple mobile application.
I want a design like this:
[image]

I need  a tip about - what is type of page i need to use?
I need  Master Detail page (for the menu in left side).

But I just don't know how I can do 3 tabs in top of screen
Its not a tabbed page because I want to use in iPhone (on top) and Android same design.
How i can to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the menu behavior you have to use a [Master Detail Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/).

As you told the [TabbedPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/tabbed-page/) tabs will be rendered in the bottom of iOS and in the top in Android.
If you want to always have the tabs in the top I suggest you tu use a [CarouselPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/carousel-page/) and implemented the tab bar manually.

You have another option that violates iOS UI principles that I don't recommend, but you could try to use a [CustomRenderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/) for the TabbedPage and then use this [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29580094/5223160).

Comment: Ok. Thanks i will try .