# how do I add a tabbar on top of my google map?

Tags: swift, google-maps, view, swift2, uitabbar

I am trying to add a tab bar on top of my google map however, whenever I run this code xcode always crashes and tells me "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Here's my code:

```
 @IBOutlet var tabControlller: UITabBar!

override func loadView() {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(25.0330, longitude: 121.5654, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10), camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.tiltGestures = true
    mapView.settings.rotateGestures = true

    view = mapView
    view.insertSubview(tabControlller, aboveSubview: mapView)


    // Creates a marker in the center of the map
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 25.0330, longitude: 121.5654)
    marker.title = "Taipei"
    marker.snippet = "Taiwan"
    marker.map = mapView

    let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    mapView.padding = mapInsets


}
```

I am pretty sure the error comes from the    view.insertSubview(tabControlller, aboveSubview: mapView) however, I am not sure how to add that tabbar on top of my google map? Do I do it programmatically or through IB?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of unwrapping an optional variable that contains nil.

In your code `tabControlller` is an optional.

When you are using it in:

`view.insertSubview(tabControlller, aboveSubview: mapView)`

it is trying to unwrap `tabControlller` and use it. 
But till this point `tabControlller` might not be initialized to any object and so it contains nil. So when unwrapping nil , the app crashes.

That why you are getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Also `UITabBar` cannot be added to the top of the controller. Instead you can create custom control using `UISegmentedControl` or `UIToolBar`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't set UITabBar on top in iOS. you can use any custom controll.**

See this

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbar

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @PGDev's answer, in order to access an optional’s value (if it has one at all), you need to unwrap it. An optional value can be unwrapped safely or forcibly. If you force-unwrap an optional, and it didn't have a value, your program will crash with the above message. [Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170457/5832311) You should never explicitly force unwrap an optional with the `!` operator. There may be cases where using `!` is acceptable – but you should only ever be using it if you are 100% sure that the optional contains a value.

Also, [UITabBar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbar) always appear across the bottom edge of the screen and display the contents of one or more [UITabBarItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbaritem) objects. But I found some related answers that may help on how to position the `UITabBar` on top. See the links below.

- [Positioning UITabBar at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579992/positioning-uitabbar-at-the-top)
- [UITabBar on top or any other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483820/uitabbar-on-top-or-any-other)

Hope this helps!